# Mixing local and remote Docker images repo?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, repository

I work on a Kubernetes cluster based CI-CD pipeline.
The pipeline runs like this:

- An ECR machine has Docker.
- Jenkins runs as a container.
- "Builder image" with Java, Maven etc is built.
- Then this builder image is run to build an app image(s)
- Then the app is run in kubernetes AWS cluster (using Helm).
- Then the builder image is run with params to run Maven-driven tests against the app.

Now part of these steps doesn't require the image to be pushed. E.g. the builder image can be cached or disposed at will - it would be rebuilt if needed.

So these images are named like `mycompany/mvn-builder:latest`.

This works fine when used directly through Docker.

When Kubernetes and Helm comes, it wants the images URI's, and try to fetch them from the remote repo. So using the "local" name `mycompany/mvn-builder:latest` doesn't work:

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for collab/collab-services-api-mvn-builder, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Technically, I can name it `<AWS-repo-ID>/mvn-builder` and push it, but that breaks the possibility to run all this locally in `minikube`, because that's quite hard to keep authenticated against the silly AWS 12-hour token (remember it all runs in a cluster).

Is it possible to mix the remote repo and local cache? In other words, can I have Docker look at the remote repository and if it's not found or fails (see above), it would take the cached image?

So that if I use `foo/bar:latest` in a Kubernetes resource, it will try to fetch, find out that it can't, and would take the local `foo/bar:latest`?

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* an `initContainer` would do that, provided it had access to `/var/run/docker.sock` (and your cluster allows such a thing) by conditionally pulling (or `docker load`-ing) the image, such that when the "main" `container` starts, the image will always be cached.

Approximately like this:

```
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: prime-the-cache
    image: docker:18-dind
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      if something_awesome; then
          docker pull from/a/registry
      else
          docker load -i some/other/path
      fi
    volumeMounts:
    - name: docker-sock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.lock
      readOnly: true
  containers:
  - name: primary
    image: a-local-image
volumes:
- name: docker-sock
  hostPath:
     path: /var/run/docker.sock
```